# Handle global exceptions in VB

Tags: vb.net, exception

Hello I have this project experiencing some problems with what is supposed to be my codes for the "problem" handler.

```
Public Event UnhandledException As UnhandledExceptionEventHandler

 Private Sub form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Dim currentDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain

            AddHandler currentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf MyHandler
        End Sub

    Sub MyHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
            Dim e As Exception = DirectCast(args.ExceptionObject, Exception)

            Using sw As New StreamWriter(File.Open(myFilePath, FileMode.Append))
                sw.WriteLine(Date.now & e.toString)
            End Using

            MessageBox.Show("An unexcpected error occured. Application will be terminated.")
            Application.Exit()
        End Sub

        Private Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
            Throw New Exception("Dummy Error")
        End Sub
```

I'm trying to globally catch all exceptions and create logfile during runtime, which works fine in the debugger(exception handling and textfile writing) but cannot catch any unhandled exceptions after I build it in the setup project and Installed into a machine. What am I missing? Do I need to include additional components to my setup project? Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does the handler run at all - ie. if you move the `MessageBox` to be the first line in the handler do you see it? It could be that you are getting an error in the handler (for instance around the logging?)

Comment: I tried moving the MessageBox to the first line of the handler and yes it shows up. I tried placing breakpoint to the beginning of handler and step in and flowed right through the handler

Comment: Are the permissions on the log file ok for the user running the application?

Comment: Yes the **myFilePath** is pointed to appdata local folder

Comment: OK - so if you move the MessageBox to the first line of the handler it shows up on the built version of the application (ie. the handler is being called) but the logging does not occur?

Comment: Ok I tried recompiling and installed. And as @theduck suggested, the messagebox didnt show, so it never calls the handler. Runs just fine in the debugger though

Comment: Does it work if you use `AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf MyHandler` - you need to change the signature of the handler slightly. Think this will work in the build and not in VS.

Comment: sounds very promising but stuff about thread is a whole new introduction to me. Im going to give it a try though, thanks for directions @theduck

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is already a way to handle exceptions for the entire application.  Embedding the handler in a form means they would only be caught and logged if and while that form was open.

1. Go to **Project -> Properties -> Application** and click the "View Application Events" button at/near the bottom.
2. This will open `ApplicationEvents.vb`.
3. Select `(MyApplicationEvents)` in the left menu; and `UnhandledException` in the right.  This opens an otherwise typical event handler to which you can add code:

   ```
   Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(sender As Object,
                                                e As ApplicationServices.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException

       Dim myFilePath As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),
                                               "badjuju.log")

       Using sw As New StreamWriter(File.Open(myFilePath, FileMode.Append))
           sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now)
           sw.WriteLine(e.Exception.Message)
       End Using

       MessageBox.Show("An unexcpected error occured. Application will be terminated.")
       End

   End Sub
   ```

This will not catch exceptions while the IDE is running because VS catches them first so you can see them and fix them.