# Global Exception Handler via Class Library - Exposing MyApplication?

Tags: vb.net

I've been trying to write an external class library for my program. This would be to act as an easier-to-implement Global Exception handler. I've taken a look at [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488132/handle-global-exceptions-in-vb). I've implemented that myself within my own project's code. My aim, now, is to stick that code in a library which can be instantiated so it can handle the exceptions easily with no hassle whatsoever.

```
Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(sender As Object, e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException

End Sub
```

The above is the handler in my main form. Now, in a class library, how can I create a handler when `New()` is called? I've tried adding a parameter such as `m As My.MyApplication`, however I get this error:

> 'm' cannot expose type 'MyApplication' outside the project through class 'xxx'.

While I understand this was a long shot, I had no clue whatsoever.

Would anyone be able to guide me along as to how I should approach this?

Kind regards,
Alex.

Comment: Are you still having trouble solving this? I haven't heard anything from you... :)

Comment: @VisualVincent sorry about that, yeah I've marked your answer now. You've solved my issue - cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [**`AppDomain.UnhandledException` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) instead you will be able to do so. It's part of the entire .NET Framework and not just Visual Basic.

```
Public Sub AppDomain_UnhandledException(sender As Object, e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
    Dim ex As Exception = DirectCast(e.ExceptionObject, Exception)
    'Do your logging of 'ex' here.
End Sub
```

In some other part of your code:

```
AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf <some class here>.AppDomain_UnhandledException
```

Comment: Using this, I do not have to provide parameters to `New()`, I can use this and it will detect the application automatically? Sorry, bit unfamiliar in this area.

Comment: @AlexM. : Yes. It will catch unhandled exceptions in the current application domain (appdomain). Every .NET application and its referenced DLLs run in the same appdomain.

Comment: @AlexM. : For more info see [**Application Domains**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bh4z9hs(v=vs.110).aspx) on the MSDN.

Comment: Ah, alright. Thank you for that information, it shall prove useful in future :)